# On hosting my react app on heroku, api calls doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, heroku, flask, hosting

I'm trying to host my react app on Heroku. I have VM instance on google with a flask rest API, the rest API works well, the react app also works in my local but when I host it, the API calls doesn't work on the react app. I have my API calls like this: axios.get(`http://10.0.0.1:8080/user`) (the 10.0.0.1 is just illustrative).

Its not API issue, i've accessed it from other sources.

Any suggestions, please help!!

Comment: What is the error in the console when you make API calls from React?

Comment: React is a client side framework. So heroku is not the reason of your problem. In order to test you could host the result of your npm run build here https://www.000webhost.com/ and try again!

Comment: thank you, since it's my first working with hosting and it didn't show any errors, I didn't think about opening the console, I opened the console and saw that it was a mixed content error, my API calls needed to be https, I'm working on it